# Create a new column from two other columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two columns, I want to create a new column called `class`:

```
class_desc    class_title 
-------------------------
class 1       class 1
class 2       NA
class 4       class 2
```

I tried this code but it didn't work :

```
data_R2 <- data_R2 %>%
  mutate(class = ifelse(class_desc == class_title,
                        class-desc,
                        ifelse(class_title == class_desc,
                               class_title,
                               NA
                        )))
```

This is the desired output:

```
class_desc    class_title   class
-----------------------------------
class 1       class 1       class 1
class 2       NA            class 2
class 4       class 2       NA
NA            NA            NA
```

Comment: `ifelse(class_desc == class_title` and `ifelse(class_title == class_desc` it seems you're asking the same thing twice.

Comment: Possibly a typo? "class-desc" should be "class_desc"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class` is a keyword in R, so I've called the new column `class_`.

I'm not quite clear what your logic is supposed to be, but in trying to guess what might lead to your output just for fun, I had strange behaviour with `ifelse` and `NA`. This is covered in this article: https://datacornering.com/ifelse-and-na-problem-in-r/.

They suggest `case_when` instead of nested `ifelse`.

I just guessed that you want `class_desc` if `class_title` is `NA`. Try out this scaffold for whatever your actual criteria happens to be.

```
data_R2 %>% mutate(class_ = case_when(
    class_desc == class_title ~ class_desc, 
    is.na(class_title) ~ class_desc,
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
)
```

Edit: to be explicit in the default case, I've added `TRUE ~ NA_character_`. Just `NA` gave me an error, which I resolved using this page: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3202

```
  class_desc class_title  class_
1    class 1     class 1 class 1
2    class 2        <NA> class 2
3    class 4     class 2    <NA>
4       <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: 11574713 perfect! it solved it with some modifications, thanks!